# LinqtoSQL/C#: How to use ternary statement in this situation

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have the following Linq to SQL:

```
var finalResults =

    (from d in data
    group d by new { d.LocationName, d.Year, d.Month, d.Denominator, d.Numerator } into groupItem
    orderby groupItem.Key.Year, groupItem.Key.Month, groupItem.Key.LocationName 
    select new
    {
        IndicatorName = IndicatorName,
        groupItem.Key.LocationName,
        Year = string.Format("{0}", (int?)groupItem.Key.Year),
        Month = string.Format("{0:00}", (int?)groupItem.Key.Month)                     
        Numerator = groupItem.Sum(x => x.Numerator),
        groupItem.Key.Denominator,

    }).ToList();
```

The problem is that there are some empty strings in both the Year and Month.  When this happens, I want to replace the empty string with a "Not Available".  I tried doing a ternary statement like this:

```
Year = string.Format("{0}", (int?)groupItem.Key.Year) == "" ? "Not Available" :  string.Format("{0}", (int?)groupItem.Key.Year),
Month = string.Format("{0:00}", (int?)groupItem.Key.Month) == "" ? "Not Available" :  string.Format("{0:00}", (int?)groupItem.Key.Month),
```

What I was trying to do was "if Year (or Month) has an empty string, display "Not Available" otherwise display the value

However, this does not do what I though it would do because I still fail my

Assert.AreNotEqual("", endItem.Year);
  Assert.AreNotEqual("", endItem.Month);

tests.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly recommend doing the final manipulation in LINQ to Objects instead. Project all the bits you need in LINQ to SQL, then use `AsEnumerable` to get back to LINQ to Objects:

```
var sqlQuery = from d in data
               group d by new { d.LocationName, d.Year, d.Month, 
                                d.Denominator, d.Numerator } into groupItem
               orderby groupItem.Key.Year, groupItem.Key.Month, 
                       groupItem.Key.LocationName 
               select new
               {
                   IndicatorName,
                   groupItem.Key.LocationName,
                   groupItem.Key.Year,
                   groupItem.Key.Month,
                   Numerator = groupItem.Sum(x => x.Numerator),
                   groupItem.Key.Denominator,
               };

var finalResult = sqlQuery.AsEnumerable()
     .Select(item => new {
                 item.IndicatorName,
                 item.LocationName,
                 Year = item.Year == null ? "Not Available" 
                                          : item.Year.ToString(),
                 Month = item.Month == null ? "Not Available" 
                                            : item.Month.ToString("00"),
                 item.Numerator,
                 item.Denominator
             })
     .ToList();
```

It's much easier to reason about what's going to happen in complicated scenarios when you're using LINQ to Objects - you don't need to worry about differences in null handling etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you comparing formatted values and raw ones?

```
Year = groupItem.Key.Year == "" ? "Not Available" :  string.Format("{0}", (int?)groupItem.Key.Year),
Month = groupItem.Key.Month == "" ? "Not Available" :  string.Format("{0:00}", (int?)groupItem.Key.Month),
```

Comment: I didn't think about doing it that way but when I tried I get the error "The '==' operator cannot be applied to oeprands of int and string."

Comment: So it means your `Year` and `Month` are not empty strings, as you've written, but `int`s. And being `int`s they can't be empty, so that's why your tests always fail. All of that means that your data *source* is somehow wrong.